# White image background in the top status bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Since today the three badges and StackExchange images have an ugly white background in all common browsers.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the images were accidently commited without transparency. Not pretty, I agree :)

This is fixed now, thanks!

Comment: This was my fault. I was updating the sprite to have the new envelope icon suggested here: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/320/can-anything-be-done-to-make-the-unread-items-icon-more-clear but somehow the transparency was not preserved. I have pushed another update, should be on prod soon.